# jersey webservices post url 403 forbidden error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat7, jersey-2.0

i have issue with restful webservices POST url when i'm calling outside the server through POSTMAN. It works fine locally on windows server through POSTMAN.

I have GET URL's which are working fine remotely and locally.

I tried disabling firewalls on windows server but it does not work.

webservices war file is deployed into Tomcat 7.

Need help to troubleshoot this issue, please advice.

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm having the exact same problem and is driving me crazy